# I created archive node on GCP but I cannot access historical data when using the beacon api?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created archive node on GCP but I cannot access historical data when using the beacon api? I am trying to get the balance of my validator using the beacon node I spun up on gcp (using their blockchain node engine) looking way back but it gives result:
"error": {
"code": 500,
"message": "NOT_FOUND: beacon state at slot 7856549",
"stacktraces": [],
"status": ""
}

what should I do?